# Trouble with react native layout

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with my react native layout iPhone 5c.

[image: iPhone 5c layout]

But iPhone 7 and iPad look good.

[image: iPad layout]

How to fix it?

My buttons code:

```
  _renderButton(title, onPress, active) {
    var style = (active) ? styles.activeButtonText : styles.buttonText;

    return (
      <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={onPress}>
        <Text style={style}>
          {title}
        </Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.controls}>
           {this._renderButton("LISTEN", () => {this._playOriginalAudio()})}
           {this._renderButton(this.state.recordingText, () => {this._record()}, this.state.recording )}
           {this._renderButton("LISTEN TO RECORDING", () => {this._play()} )}
           {this._renderButton("SUBMIT", () => {this._send()} )}
        </View>
      </View>
      );
    }
  }

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#2b608a",
  },
  controls: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  button: {
    padding: 20
  },
  disabledButtonText: {
    color: '#eee'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#fff"
  },
  activeButtonText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#B81F00"
  },
  points: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 72,
    left: 56,
    width: 90,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#69d2e7',
    fontSize: 50,
    fontWeight: "100"
  },
  headerText: {
    paddingBottom: 10,
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#69d2e7"
  }

});
```

I've tried to test app with iPhone 5 simulator, and I have no any style problem. Looks like the problem only with real iPhone 5 device. Maybe it is bug.

[image]

Comment: Add your style sheet code here.

Comment: @IrfanAli I've added style code too.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to see your specific style sheet, but I am guessing you would benefit by importing the Dimensions module that React Native provides.

[Dimensions Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html#get)

Then you can get the height and width of the device your app is running on, to change the styles appropriately.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. Strange why react native doesn't change styles automatically.

Comment: I've tried to test app with iPhone 5 simulator, and I have no any style problem. Looks like the problem only with real iPhone 5 device. Maybe it is bug.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, I think they try to auto scale font as much as they can. You could also try: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html ... it looks like PixelRatio.get() returns a 2 for iPhone 5, 5c, etc. That could be one more option if you really want to try targeting that specific screen. It could also be a production bug as well, I haven't really tried many apps in that phone. @Rasvet